# Query that counts rows for a extra column for a select

Tags: sql, ssms-2014

I would like to make a viww that find the top 5 highest quantity items from a characters inventory but also a column that shows how many other people also has the item.

- CHARACTERS

  - CHARID PK
- INVENTORY

  - ITEMID
  - CHARID
  - quantity
- ITEM

  - ITEMID

This is what I got so far

```
CREATE VIEW vwTop5
 AS
SELECT TOP 5 INVENTORY.itemID, INVENTORY.charID,quantity,COUNT(SELECT * 
FROM INVENTORY)
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE INVENTORY.charID = 3
```

I know this what above is wrong but could you guys please show me what to do to fix it? :)

Comment: TOP 5, but no ORDER BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close :

```
CREATE VIEW vwTop5
 AS
SELECT TOP 5 INVENTORY.itemID, INVENTORY.charID,quantity,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVENTORY) as cnt
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE INVENTORY.charID =
```

Like @FelixPamittan said, you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to specify which `TOP 5` records you want.

Comment: Yea, but `ORDER BY` what? :)